# Can I invoking java web start in program?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I want to make use of the java web start advantage,but I dont want our customer face the java web start loading Screen,it seems ugly...and also customer maybe not install jre and the jre-install maybe fussy to them..so I want to package our application and jre into setup file using installanywhere. when user start our program,I want to invoking web start API to do the work like version compare,and offer outself loading screen ..
so,Can I invoking web start in my program?and how?
Best regards
L.J.W

Answer (score 1):

I don't think web start is the way you want to go here. You can't change the loading screen, and if you want to access the user's computer in any way you'll have to bother the user with a confirmation, and risk them freaking out and canceling. Just roll your own auto-update; it's definitely not worth using web start just for that.

Comment: Depends on what you consider light. This library: http://swing-fx.blogspot.com/2008/07/add-auto-update-and-plugins-to-your.html will give you auto-update and plugin capability; the jar is 88k. That's not too bad, but it might be overkill if you don't need plugins. (It's released under the BSD license.)

Answer (score 1):

For the loading screen question:

```
<jnlp ...>
    <information>
        <icon kind="splash" href="splash.gif" />
        ...
    </information>
    ...
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're installing your application locally on the user's machine, why would you need to call JWS?

Comment: I want to auto upgrade our program,I think jws/jnlp has done this work.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer